# Address before appendix in amsart

Tags: appendices, amsart, keywords, addresses

I am writing an article using `amsart` class and because I'm having a little problem with placing the address, I'd like to ask for your help.

If I use predefined commands to print out the address (school, town etc.) and email, they appear at the very end of the document (last page of text). But I would like them to appear before the appendix, as in my case it's only a set of figures...

Also if I use predefined keywords command, they get printed in footnotes. How would I get them printed under (after) the abstract and in the same formatting as abstract?

Do you know any simple way of doing that?

Enclosing minimal working example...

Thanks a lot in advance.

Emil

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}    %and others

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Title}

\author[Emil Skrisovsky]{Emil Skrisovsky\textsuperscript{1}}

\address{\textsuperscript{1}Faculty of Mathematics and Physics, Charles University. Prague, Czech Republic.}

\email{emil.skrisovsky@gmail.com}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.....
\end{abstract}

\maketitle   %prints out Title, Author and Abstract (all in smallcaps)

%here is the contents, several pages of text 
%introduction, main part, conclusion

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%references
\end{thebibliography}

% i'd like to have the address placed here

\newpage
\begin{appendix}
%lots of figures
\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about inserting `\addresses` there?

Comment: regarding the keywords, your best approach is to just include them as a final paragraph in the abstract, and don't use the `\keywords` command.  (of course, this will mean that "automatic indexing" programs probably won't find them.)  moving the addresses may be possible, but will require some nonstandard coding; i'll take a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The addresses are stored in the macro `\enddoc@text` that is executed with `\AtEndDocument`. So we can define a new command that uses the macro and redefines it to do nothing.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}    %and others

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addresseshere}{%
  \enddoc@text\let\enddoc@text\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title[short title]{Title}

\author[Emil Skrisovsky]{Emil Skrisovsky\textsuperscript{1}}

\address{\textsuperscript{1}Faculty of Mathematics and Physics, 
  Charles University. Prague, Czech Republic.}

\email{emil.skrisovsky@gmail.com}

\keywords{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, ...}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract.....
\end{abstract}

\maketitle   %prints out Title, Author and Abstract (all in smallcaps)

%here is the contents, several pages of text 
%introduction, main part, conclusion

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
%references
\end{thebibliography}

% i'd like to have the address placed here
\addresseshere


\newpage
\appendix

some figures here


\end{document}
```

Note that there is no `appendix` environment.

[image]

The text “some figures here” goes on the next page.